# How to implement a modular system

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I'm designing a very big system that I will implement with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.2 (but I think this is not relevant for my question).

This system will have modules that I can use it in one computer or not. For example, if I'm using my system to track datamatrix read by a camera, I will use a module to read datamatrix, but in another installation I'm not going to install that module because I'm not going to read datamatrix.

In a few words, my system will be a windows desktop application with a lot of user controls that I can use to manage some functions if those functions are available.

All of those modules could save statistics. For example, in the module with the camera to read datamatrix I would like to store the number of datamatrix, how many I read in a minute, wrongs datamatrix read, etc. This is not the function for this module, so I need to create another module to manage this statistics.

Sometimes I will use statistics, but sometimes no. So, I need a mechanism to prepare all modules to use the statistics modules:

1. Add a call to a method of statistics' module to save data.
2. Add a way to plug the statistics' module to another module and don't do anything else to use it.

In a nutshell, add a way to use statistics module if I have "plug-in" it into the datamatrix module, and don't use if I haven't plug-in it.

I need to do something to prepare datamatrix module to use statistics module if I have plugged-in, but don't throw any error if I haven't plugged-in.

I think I need to implement an interface for statistics module and a way to add an instance of that module to datamatrix module. And, on datamatrix module, check if statistics module if available before use it.

What do you think? Is there a pattern to make this?

Comment: you probably want to take an OOP approach, definitely for the statistics and them make some static classes and put them in a library (.dll) for your shared methods

Comment: If your modules have interfaces, you need only setup a save/load for each and call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
public interface IStatisticsModule {
    bool Enabled { get; }
    void Save(object stuff);
    // whatever else it can do
}

class NullStatistics : IStatisticsModule {
    public bool Enabled => false;

    public void Save(object stuff) {
        // do nothing or throw
    }
}

class RealStatisticsModule : IStatisticsModule {
    public bool Enabled => true;
    public void Save(object stuff) {
        // save
    }
}

public class DataMatrixModule {
    private readonly IStatisticsModule _stats;

    public DataMatrixModule(IStatisticsModule stats) {
        _stats = stats;
    }

    public void SomeOperation() {
        if (_stats.Enabled)
            _stats.Save(null);
    }
}
```

So you always inject `IStatisticsModule` to other modules, but when you don't really need to collect stats - you inject dummy `NullStatistics` which implements the same interface but does nothing. Also include `Enabled` property so that modules may decide to not perform expensive computations of stats when it's not really needed. If computation is not expensive - module can even omit `IsEnabled` check and just call respective method which will do nothing if stats are not needed.

That's essentially how all loggers work, they have something like `Debug()` and `IsDebugEnabled`, but you can omit that `IsDebugEnabled` check and just call `Debug()` if argument to that function is not computationally expensive. If debug was disabled - it will just do nothing.